# What is conditional distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Can you explain conditional distribution in the simplest sense?

Answer (score 1):

We can denote $x_C\in C$ as a point that is in $C$. Likewise, we can define $x_B\in B$, and $x_{C/B}$ as a point that is in $C$ but not in $B$.
Then, given $x_i$ is always chosen from $B$, we have the following cases for $p(x|x\in B)$:

1) $x\in C/B$: Then $p(x|x\in B)=0$

2) $x\in B$: Then $p(x|x\in B)=\dfrac{1}{|B|}$, where $|B|$ is the cardinality of the set $B$.

Basically this is the same as $X\sim Unif(B)$.

Comment: Nope, that is basically it.  By Bayes' Rule we have: $${\mathsf P(X=x\mid X\in B) ~{~=~ \dfrac{\mathsf P(X=x)\,\mathsf P(X\in B\mid X=x)}{\sum\limits_{k\in B}\mathsf P(X=k)\,\mathsf P(X\in B\mid X=k)}\\~=~ \dfrac{\lvert C\rvert ^{-1}\cdot \big[x\in B\big]}{\lvert B\rvert\cdot\lvert C\rvert^{-1}}\\ ~=~\lvert B\rvert ^{-1}\cdot\big[ x\in B\big]}\\}$$Therefore $X\mid X\in B ~\sim~\mathcal U\mathrm{nif}(B)$