# Conditional distribution of a discrete uniform random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I have the following from Joseph Blitzstein's Introduction to probability:

*Let $X \sim DUnif(C)$, and $B$ be a nonempty subset of $C$. Find the conditional distribution
of $X$, given that $X$ is in $B$.*

Following is my attempts:

$\begin{align}
P(X=k\mid X\in B) &= \frac{P(X\in B|X=k)P(X=k)}{P(X\in B)}\\
 &=  \frac{[P(X\in B|k\in B, X=k)P(k\in B|X=k) + P(X\in B| k\notin B, X=k)P(k\notin B|X=k)]P(X=k)}{P(X\in B)}\\
&=\frac{P(k \in B| X=k)P(X=k)}{P(X\in B)}\\
&=\frac{P(X=k|k\in B)P(k\in B)}{P(X\in B)}
\end{align}$

However, I am stuck on how to interpret $P(k\in B)$ since $k$ is a free variable if my understanding of the definition of a PMF is correct.

After looking online for solutions, I stumbled on this old post [What is conditional distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2471206/what-is-conditional-distribution/2471304) and it seems like I used an approach similar to one of the answers. However, in that post, it is stated that $P(X=k\mid X\in B) = 1/|B|$, which makes me wonder if in my case, $P(k\in B) = P(X\in B)$ and  $P(X=k|k\in B) = 1/|B|$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is  uniformly distributed over $C$, then the probability that $X$ lies in $B\subset C$ is the relative cardinality $|B|/|C|$. In particular, $P(X=k) = 1/|C|$. And also $P(X=k, X\in B) = P(X=k)$ or $0$, according as $k\in B$ or not. From this you'll be able to work out $P(X=k\mid X\in B)$.

Comment: I am still not able to finish the analysis
We have $P(X=k, X\in B) = P(X=k, X\in B| k\in B)P(k\in B) + P(X=k, X\in B| k\notin B)P(k\notin B)$

This means $P(X=k, X\in B) = P(X=k, X\in B| k\in B)P(k\in B)$ 
I think that since $k\in B$, we have $P(X=k, X\in B| k\in B) = P(X = k| k \in B)$
But then, I still have $P(k\in B)$ that I do not know how to interpret

Comment: For $k\in B$,
$$
P(X=k\mid X\in B) = {P(X=k, X\in B)\over P(X\in B)}
={P(X=k)\over P(X\in B)}={|\{k\}|/|C|\over |B|/|C|}={1\over |B|}.
$$